# BDD Cucumber test for IE is not working in locked windows machine

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, hover, mouse, locked

i am running BDD cucumber test via jenkins in slave node windows machine for IE browser. since machine is locked my test start with browser opening and login into site but when it does mouse hover thru menu it fails due to machine lock

i have tried few registry settings for minimized browser

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, any test that requires moving the mouse or sending key strokes requires an unlocked desktop. So, in your scenario, you could try to prevent the machine locked.Try to refer to the following work-arounds:

- Use a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) product. With this they remotely connect to the test
  machine, leave the user logged on, but disconnect the VNC connection.
  This leaves the Windows session open and unlocked, but humans still
  cannot access it without reconnecting the VNC connection (which
  usually means re-authenticating).
- [Keep an Active Session](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/knowledge-base/scheduling-kb/keep-active-session) Running on the server.
- Set registry keys to work with a [Minimized Remote Desktop Connection](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/knowledge-base/test-execution-kb/minimized-rdc).

Reference: [No Tests Execute on Locked Machine](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/knowledge-base/test-execution-kb/locked-machine)

Answer (score 0):

VNC is not a option for me since it is not a approved prodcut.

keep active session i tried for same machine with jenkins and localhost but since 1 jenkins agent job is running it doesnt support

Minimized RDC configured, its not helping for BDD script but helped for UFT test.

This is more on mouse hover issue in IE, test starts and it open IE browser, goto URL and key in credentials... this is fine.
once it enter after login, test doesnt go thru menu which is more towards mouse hovering activity. Please let me know if anything specific i can do with registry, machine settings or code that can help for mouse hover